# Topology-first countable axiom

Tags: general-topology

Please help me to prove the following statement:

In a first countable $T_1$ space, every point is a $G_\delta$ set.

A space is first countable if it has a countable base. Also in a $T_1$ space every singleton is closed. So how can I use these to prove the above statement?

Comment: You might also take a look at [$G_\delta$ singletons in compact Hausdorff and first countability](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240472/g-delta-singletons-in-compact-hausdorff-and-first-countability) for sort of the converse statement.

Answer (score 6):

First remember that a space is first countable if it has a countable base *locally*, that is, for any point $x$, there is a countable collection of open sets such that any open set containing $x$ contains one of these open sets. Edit: These open sets are neighborhoods of $x$, not just any open sets. Thanks to Stefan H. for pointing this out.

A $G_\delta$ set is a set that is a countable intersection of open sets. Suppose you're given a single point $x$ in a first-countable $T_1$ space. What is a natural countable collection of open sets to try to intersect to get $\{x\}$? Why does this give you only $\{x\}$? (Hint: you haven't used the $T_1$ property yet).

Comment: There is a minor flaw in your formulation. The countable collection of open sets has to be a countable collection of neighborhoods of $x$. I guess that is what you meant. For example in the quotient space $\mathbb {R/Z}$ the intervalls $(n,\ n+\frac1k),\ n,k\in\mathbb Z-\{0\}$ form a countable family of open sets for the point $\{\mathbb Z\}$ with that property. But $\{\mathbb Z\}$ does not have a countable local base.

Comment: Stefan H. is right (in principle, I'm not sure about the example given...). For reference, such a collection is called a local $\pi$-base, and the corresponding property is countable $\pi$-character (denoted $\pi\chi(X)\leq \aleph_0$ using the notation of the Handbook of set-theoretic topology).

Comment: @StefanH.: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the collection you specified fail to have the property by $U=(\bigcup (k-\frac{1}{\lvert k \rvert},k+\frac{1}{\lvert k\rvert})/_\sim$?

Comment: For a more accessible (to me, at least) example, consider an uncountable set $X'$ and the space $X=\{x_0\}\sqcup X'$ with the topology given by basis of all cofinite subsets of $X$ containing $\{x_0\}$ and $\{x_0\}$ itself. Then for any $x\neq x_0$ we have that $\{x_0\}$ is in every neigbhourhood of $x$ (indeed, it is in any open set), but the intersection of any countable family of neighbourhoods of $x$ is cocountable, so no such family forms a basis of neighbourhoods of $x$.

Comment: @StefanH.: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @tomasz:  Your set $U$ does contain an intervall $(n, n-\frac1{|n|})$. Actually it is the image of this intervall under the quotient map.

Comment: @StefanH.: That's right, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ first-countable and $T_1$ and $x\in X$. Suppose that $\{V_1,V_2,... \}$ be a countable basis at point $x$. We **claim** that $\bigcap V_i=\{x\}$.

If $y\in \bigcap V_i$ where $x\not=y$, then there is an open nbhood $U$ of $x$ which does not contain $y$. But then some $V_i$ is contained in $U$ and also does not contain $y$. It follows that $y=x$. Hence $\{x\}$ is a $G_\delta$-set.

Answer (score 1):

A first countable space is a space which has countable basis *at each point*, not necessarily globally.

Hint: Choose any point $x_0$, and a countable basis $U_n$ of neighbourhoods of $x_0$. What is $\bigcap_n U_n$?